# Excel count and extract distinct combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of products where I need to count how many times each product appears which I have done using =countif() in another column.
[Example Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSLBh.png)

Now I want to go through my products column and return each distinct value with the value in my count column. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just use a Pivot Table.

Comment: The newer xl has a [UNIQUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e).

Comment: Copy your entire table, paste values to another range, use Remove Duplicates on that range

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a countif of each instance, change the formula to countif the amount of occurrences as they appear in the expanding range and then autofilter for the 1 in the result column
   `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)` [image]

Comment: I see with your method my last occurrence has the highest and final count. But I'm not sure I'm understanding how this solves my question of then only showing that final count with only distinct product names? So in your example above, we'd only see Apple, Banana, Apricot with their final counts.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood but don't you wish to see only the unique values in A? If so, you can copy that filtered list and then associate the count for each

Comment: What filter are you referring to?

Comment: Autofilter on the countif column